# How can I convert an array to string in swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I want to convert an array to string like this

```swift
let myArray:[Any] = ["element 1", "element 2", ["element 3.1", "element 3.2"], "element 4"]
```

to

```swift
let convertedString = "[\"element 1\",\"element 2\",\"[\\\"element 3.1\\\",\\\"element 3.2\\\"]\",\"element 4\"]"
```

I have tried this

```swift
do {
    let jsonData: Data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: myArray, options: [])
    if  let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
        print(jsonString)
    }

} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Array convertIntoJSON - \(error.description)")
}
```

However I get this result

```
["element 1","element 2",["element 3.1","element 3.2"],"element 4"]
```

I have done this in java by using JSONArray. I just call toString method to do this in java. I need to get third element as a string like given example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
"\(myArray.map { "\($0)" })"
```